# Combining 2 queries into 1 query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert

Let's assume I have a structure as;

```
{
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  id: 1,
  children: [
      {id: 2, name: "", age: ""},
      {id: 3, name: "", age: ""}
  ]
}
```

I want to add new children or update the existing children fields according to situation.

To add new children into the list, I wrote query which is;

```
  db.collection.update({id: 1}, {
    $push: {
        children: {
            name: "alex",
            age: 12,
            id : shortid.generate()                
       }
    }
}, {
    upsert:true
},function(err, result) {

}
```

Whether it is a insert or update, I should update the document with id 1. So I think about combining these 2 situations into 1 query.

If I want to add children to the children array I should use $push, otherwise if it is an update I should update the fields of children object. So by using $cond I wrote a query like this;

```
db.collection.update({id: 1}, 
        {
          $cond : {
           if: {id: {$exists: 21}} , 
           then: {
              $set: {
                 children: {  name: "new name", age: "new age"}
               }
           }, 
          else: {  
            $push: {
              children: {
                  name: "alex",
                  age: 12,
                  id : 21                
              }
           }
         }
    }, {
        upsert:true
    },function(err, result){}
```

And I see it is not possible to have such query, I got an error. Was it too unrealistic? Should I take this two situation separately? I think it was a good idea because I update the same document with id:1 whether it's a update or insert. The only change is deciding whether I will set the fields or create and push them into the children array. What do you suggest for this situation? And yes, I admit, I'm trying to get some experience with mongodb and $cond.

Comment: upset : true means same thing. if document exists, simply update it, otherwise insert new one with provided values. Like every other programming language, there are defined rules. what you can add after a given keyword or statement. Same holds true with MongoDB.  Check documentation to see if $cond is supported in `update`?

Comment: @saleem Allright upsert does the same thing. But, I just $push. I does not check any condition.It's a update or not, it just pushes the children object with new values. Am I wrong? However, what I want to do is, edit or push in the one query.

Comment: $push is suppose to push item into array regardless of it exists or not. See $addToSet if you want to make sure no duplicate item get pushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first solution is correct and does what you want it to do. The upsert option tells mongo to check if the document exists or not. Mongo will then either insert the doc if it's not there or update an existing doc with the new values it a doc with the given id exists. You need not to do anything else.